# MYSQL timecard summary

Tags: mysql

Hi I have the below timecard structure on our system.

[image]

From the above timecard I need to generate a report that compares `start` from `time_in` AND `end` from `time_out` and group it by `emp_id`.

[image]

Any hint on how can I display it like the above would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following query does the job.

```
SELECT date, emp_id, 
    MAX(IF(event='t_in',time_in - start, 0)) AS 't1_in_diff',
    MAX(IF(event='t_out',time_out - end, 0)) AS 't1_out_diff',
    MAX(IF(event='b1_in',time_in - start, 0)) AS 'b1_in_diff',
    MAX(IF(event='b1_out',time_out - end, 0)) AS 'b1_out_diff',
FROM timecard 
GROUP BY date, emp_id;
```

If results can be negative (time_in/time_out can be smaller than start/end), you should set 0 to a value that is always smaller than the difference.